# How can I retrieve a Facebook id from a link

Tags: facebook, url, hyperlink

I would like to retrieve a the facebook id from a link. What I would like to know is if I've got all the possible cases or/and if I can have a standard way to do it ex :

If have http://www.facebook.com/pages/ExchangeMyRooms/301768493253094
I can retrieve the id from the URL

If I have http://www.facebook.com/babelverse I do :
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=babelverse
and I get the id

If I have http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/ I do : https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/
and I get the id

The results should look like that :

```
{
"babelverse": {
  "id": "177626422254171",
  "name": "Babelverse",
  "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/372895_177626422254171_1480242829_s.jpg",
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/babelverse",
  "likes": 957,
  ...
```

Is there a way to do a query like

SELECT id FROM idontknow WHERE link=mylink

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are just looking for the FQL equivalent of the Graph API call …?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/object_url/

Comment: Yes this is it but I don't understand something. I have this page :
http://www.exchangemyrooms.com/
I liked the URL, (my like button has this parameter
 data-href="http://www.exchangemyrooms.com")

When I do that :

https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.exchangemyrooms.com

No id appears, why ?

Comment: the url it self is the id, when you access in that method

Answer (score 0):

The page-id will be the trailing number after the seo name in the url

URL break down for pages with out `Vanity URL`.

`facebook.com/pages/` **| seo name** `ExchangeMyRooms/` **| page-id** `301768493253094`

**Try** https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=301768493253094

**Returns**

```
{
  "id": "301768493253094", 
  "name": "ExchangeMyRooms", 
  "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/yY/r/fmYdZvdquYb.png", 
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/ExchangeMyRooms/301768493253094", 
  "likes": 2, 
  "category": "Company", 
  "is_published": true, 
  "can_post": true, 
  "talking_about_count": 1
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the id without having to break the URL down ?

Comment: i think maybe i am confused at what you are trying to accomplish,  most times we just paste the page id in our code and use as string.  Why do you need to pull the id from this page on the fly?